# Ver el sdk de .NET core

Tags: asp.net

Me he instalado el SDK de .NET core desde

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Ahora quisiera verlo, no sé dónde está

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: a que te refieres con eso de querer ver? es un conjunto de librerias, quieres ver el código de dentro? o estás tras algo en particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda muy claro a que te refieres con "verlo"? no es necesario "verlo", basta con utilizarlo.

DotNet Core viene acompañado del Dotnet-CLi que es el interprete de comandos para dotnet core.

El CLI de dotnet core tiene una documentación bastante amplia (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x), sin embargo, desde cualquier terminal puedes escribir:

```
dotnet --help
```

Si quieres probar que funcione, puedes utilizar:

```
dotnet new console
```

Esto te creará una aplicación de consola que podrás editar con tu IDE favorito.

Si solo quieres validar que haya quedado instalado en tu máquina,  puedes utilizar:

```
dotnet --version
```

Esto te dirá la versión de dotnet core instalada.

Ahora, si ya quieres ver un poco de información más avanzada:

```
dotnet --info
```

Allí si puedes ver las rutas de instalación (entre otras cosas)

**UPDATE:**

Puedes encontrar la documentación oficial de DotNet, aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Por nada. Si te fue de ayuda, no olvides marcarla como respuesta  para que pueda ayudar a otros también.

Comment: No sé marcar la respuesta. ¿Dónde se hace?

Comment: Lo que quiero ver es el manual SDK de .NET core. No sé dónde se instala.

Comment: Se marca desde el "✔" que aparece a la parte izquierda de la respuesta.

Comment: Me parece que no queda documentación en tu equipo local luego de instalar, pero puedes encontrar muy buena documentación oficial aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/ (Agregado a la respuesta)